# Thinkster.io angular chapter 6 error - auth.logout() not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase

If someone who have gone through thinkster.io augularjs tutorial would be familiar with the below code. I am facing the below error.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-show="signedIn()">
    <li>
        <a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

First the logout button was not showing up.   after adding single quotes it showed up

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-show="'signedIn()'">
```

But as i click on logout the user is not getting logged out.

**nav.js code**

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Post, Auth) {
    $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};

    $scope.submitPost = function () {
      Post.create($scope.post).then(function (ref) {
        $location.path('/posts/' + ref.name());
        $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};
      });
    };

    $scope.logout = function () {
      Auth.logout();
    };

});
```

**services/auth.js code**

```
app.factory('Auth', function($firebaseSimpleLogin, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope){
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

var Auth = {
    register: function(user){
        return auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password);
    },
    signedIn: function(){
        return auth.user !== null;
    },
    logout: function(){
        auth.$logout();
    }

};
$rootScope.signedIn = function(){
    return Auth.signedIn();
};
return Auth;
```

} );

Comment: How have you determined that it doesn't work? What is the error or condition we can attempt to verify this?

Comment: See Daniel's answer below. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Since I came across this issue myself and checked the GitHub issues, here's what you need to do.

Create a `login` method on your `Auth` service, like so:

```
login: function(user) {
    return auth.$login('password', user);
}
```

Inside your auth controller, you need to login after you register, like so:

```
Auth.register($scope.user).then(function (authUser) {
    Auth.login($scope.user); // user is now logged in
});
```

Since your login method returns a promise, you can do whatever you like when the user has logged in.

Comment: yeah it is as if they did not even test out the app. its a good tutorial in that it covers a lot but i've caught at least one other major issue with this tutorial in section 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577840/thinkster-io-angularjs-tutorial-chapter-3-problems-connecting-to-firebase/24578508

Answer (score 0):

Contents of ng-show is an expression which is evaluated against the scope.  It should not be in single quotes or else you are just giving it a non-false or truthy value (not undefined, null or 0).  Since signedIn is a method of the service you must expose that method through your controller scope or otherwise make a function in the controller scope that handles the work.