# Thinkster.io Angularjs tutorial Chapter 3 - Problems connecting to Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, firebase

I'm following [this](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/S2MxGFCO0B/3-communicating-with-a-server-using-a-service-and-resource) tutorial, building an angularjs app with connection to the firebase database. I'm stuck at chapter 3 where my app is supposed to make it initial connection to the database. I kind of felt that problems were in front of me since my command prompt and jshint tells me:

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

app\scripts\controllers\posts.js
  line 0   col 0  Bad option: 'app'.
  line 8   col 1  'app' is not defined.

app\scripts\services\post.js
  line 0   col 0  Bad option: 'app'.
  line 2   col 1  'app' is not defined.

6 problems

Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

My console gives me:

```
>Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined                      post.js
>Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: PostProvider <- Post
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=PostProvider%20%3C-%20Post at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3705:19
at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3832:39)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3710:45
at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3832:39)
at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3859:13)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3880:23)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7134:28
at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:913:26)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6579:13) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

---

Why isn't my global declaration of 'app' seen by my other js-files?

(apps.js)

```
var app = angular.module('angNewsApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
])
```

(post.js)

```
'use strict';
app.factory('Post', function ($resource){
return $resource('https://sizzling-fire-1990.firebaseio.com/posts/:id.json');
});
```

**All files content are copied from the tutorial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem doing the tutorial, and It's because you didn't do that it step says:

*"If you look at your grunt terminal, you can see that there's a task called jshint that is run every time you change a javascript file. This checks your javascript for any syntax errors and gives you hints for fixing them.  Ideally we want to have no errors in our application. In .jshintrc, we can add "app": false to tell jshint about app so we can use it in all of our files without any warnings, and /* global app:true */ at the top of app.js to let jshint know that app is defined in that file."*

Like app is not a global variable, you need to add it, So you Jshintrc File looks like:

```
{

  "node": true,
  "browser": true,
  "esnext": true,
  "bitwise": true,
  "camelcase": true,
  "curly": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "immed": true,
  "indent": 2,
  "latedef": true,
  "newcap": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "quotmark": "single",
  "regexp": true,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "strict": true,
  "trailing": true,
  "smarttabs": true,
  "globals": {
    "angular": false,
    "app":false <---- Add this line
  }
}
```

And App.Js:

```
'use strict';
/* global app:true */ <---- Add this line


/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name angNewsApp
 * @description
 * # angNewsApp
 * 
 * Main module of the application.
 * 
 */


var app = angular.module('angNewsApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize'
  ])....
```

Also Add the `<script src="scripts/services/post.js"></script>` in the page.

I think you problem is that.

Comment: Thanks, great help! that solved the warings and error messages in the command prompt. I also added 
"<script src="scripts/services/post.js"></script>"
into the index.html-file to include the script. (which is described in the tutorial but I missed that part)

Comment: OH!!! yes, I forget that. Read all the tutorial carefully because sometimes don't show you code, only the instruction. :)

Comment: The tutorial message was not clear enough for me to properly add these two statements.

Comment: @StephaneEybert exactly. they did not specify 'exactly' where to place those two lines of code.

Comment: @s3z That's true, but I felt that the Author wanna keep you reading carefully the tutorial, not showing only the code to prevent only copy and paste. Remember vote the answer +1 too.

Comment: @WilfredoP Well I am not copying and pasting (Writing it out saves it to human memory better) but the author should have made it more clear.  Still, using logic, I was able to figure it out myself. I just looked it up just to make sure 100%

Comment: That extra comment wasn't necessary for me - I only needed to add the option in .jshintrc.

Comment: most of the problems has solutions inside the official documentation, thanks bro! :D